# Nodejs streams writablestream drain event not firing

Tags: node.js, macos, stream, large-files, osx-yosemite

I am trying to read in a large file, do some computation and then write to a much bigger file. To prevent excessive memory consumption, I am using streams. The problem that I am facing is that the writestream is not firing the "drain" event, which signals that the writes have been flushed to disk. In order to prevent "back-pressure", I am waiting for the drain event to be fired before I start writing to the buffer again. While debugging I found that after a .write() call returns false and the line fvfileStream.once('drain', test) is executed, the program just stops and does not do anything.

Here is the code:

```js
var fs = require('fs');

//a test function I created to see if the callback is called after drain.
var test = function(){
 console.log("Done Draining");
}

fs.readFile('/another/file/to/be/read', {
 encoding: "utf8"
}, function(err, data) {
 if (err) throw err;

 //Make an array containing tags.
 var tags = data.split('\n');

 //create a write stream.
 var fvfileStream = fs.createWriteStream('/path/TagFeatureVectors.csv');

 //read in the question posts
 var qfileStream = fs.createReadStream('/Big/file/QuestionsWithTags.csv', {
  encoding: "utf8"
 });

 var partialRow = null;
 var writable = true;
 var count = 0;

 var doRead = function() {
  var qData = qfileStream.read();
  var questions = qData.split('\n');

  if (partialRow != null) {
   questions[0] = partialRow + questions[0];
   partialRow = null;
  }

  var lastRow = questions[questions.length - 1];
  if (lastRow.charAt(lastRow.length - 1) != '\n') {
   partialRow = lastRow;
  }

  questions.forEach(function(row, index, array) {
   count++;

   var fields = row.split(',');

   console.log("Processing question number: " + count + " id: " + fields[0]);
   var tagString = fields[1];

   var regex = new RegExp(/<([^>]+)>/g);

   tags.forEach(function(tag, index, array) {
    var found = false;
    var questionTags;

    while ((questionTags = regex.exec(tagString)) != null) {
     var currentTag = questionTags[1]

     if (currentTag === tag) {
      found = true;
      break;
     }
    };

                //This is where the writestream is written to
    if (found) {
     writable = fvfileStream.write("1,", "utf8");
    }else {
     writable = fvfileStream.write("0,","utf8");
    }
   });
  });

  fvfileStream.write("\n");
 }

 qfileStream.on('readable', function() {
  if (writable) {
   doRead();
  } else {
            //Waiting for drain event.
   fvfileStream.once('drain', test);
  }
 });

 qfileStream.on('end', function() {
  fvfileStream.end();
 });
});
```

## Updated

Based on advise provided by @loganfsmyth, I implemented transform streams, but still ran into the same issue. Here is my updated code:

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var stream = require('stream');
var util = require('util');

var Transform = stream.Transform;

function FVCreator(options) {
  // allow use without new
  if (!(this instanceof FVCreator)) {
    return new FVCreator(options);
  }

  // init Transform
  Transform.call(this, options);
}

util.inherits(FVCreator, Transform);

var partialRow = null;
var count = 0;
var tags;

FVCreator.prototype._transform = function(chunk, enc, cb) {
  var that = this;
  var questions = chunk.toString().split('\n');

  if (partialRow != null) {
    questions[0] = partialRow + questions[0];
    partialRow = null;
  }

  var lastRow = questions[questions.length - 1];
  if (lastRow.charAt(lastRow.length - 1) != '\n') {
    partialRow = lastRow;
    questions.splice(questions.length - 1, 1);
  }

  questions.forEach(function(row, index, array) {
    count++;

    var fields = row.split(',');

    console.log("Processing question number: " + count + " id: " + fields[0]);
    var tagString = fields[1];

    var regex = new RegExp(/<([^>]+)>/g);

    tags.forEach(function(tag, index, array) {
      var found = false;
      var questionTags;

      while ((questionTags = regex.exec(tagString)) != null) {
        var currentTag = questionTags[1]

        if (currentTag === tag) {
          found = true;
          break;
        }
      };

      if (found) {
        that.push("1,", "utf8");
      } else {
        that.push("0,", "utf8");
      }
    });
  });

  this.push("\n", "utf8");
  cb();
};

fs.readFile('/another/file/to/be/read', {
  encoding: "utf8"
}, function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;

  //Make an array containing tags.
  tags = data.split('\n');

  //write to a file.
  var fvfileStream = fs.createWriteStream('/path/TagFeatureVectors.csv');

  //read in the question posts
  var qfileStream = fs.createReadStream('/large/file/to/be/read', {
    encoding: "utf8"
  });

  var fvc = new FVCreator();

  qfileStream.pipe(fvc).pipe(fvfileStream);
});
```

I am running this on OSX Yosemite.

Comment: Have you looked into making this use a `stream.Transform` instance? It generally makes handing backpressure implementations much easier.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I implemented transform streams. Ran into same issue.